# Как при помощи хука изменить автора и сообщение коммита

Tags: git, git-commit

Возможно ли создать такой хук, который бы выполнялся **перед** `commit` и изменял некоторым образом сообщение коммита и правил имя/почту автора коммита?

Я знаю про команду `git filter-branch`, но она работает уже после того, как коммит сделан и даже, возможно, отправлен на сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить сообщение довольно легко.  Вот пример
`.git/hooks/commit-msg`, который заменяет `foo` на
`bar`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' -i -- "$1"
```

(При использовании *GNU sed*.)

С авторством всё посложнее.  Найти, как сделать это через хуки, пока
не смог.  Вы можете изменить имя автора для конкретного проекта через
конфиг:

```sh
$ git config --add user.email 'author@example.com'
$ git config --add user.name 'A U Thor'
$
```